# Confusion about bounded derivative implies uniform continuity

Tags: real-analysis, definition, uniform-continuity

I'm currently learning about uniform continuity and was introduced to an intuitive way of "seeing" uniform continuity by observing the derivative of the function across an interval. Notably, if the derivative is bounded, this implies uniform continuity. That made sense for some examples but I've come across an example which confuses me. Let $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$. I've proven using the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition that this function is in fact uniformly continuous on its domain, $[0,\infty)$, but the derivative of $\sqrt{x}$ is tending to $+\infty$ as $x\rightarrow0^+$. To me, this isn't a bounded derivative and therefore that "intuitive" way of visualizing uniform continuity doesn't work here. What I'm hoping for is to understand why this is so (obviously my interpretation of this fact must be flawed), and secondly is this the best way to look at a function and to interpret uniform continuity?

Comment: Bounded derivative is stronger than uniform continuity. A bounded derivative limits the slope, whereas, as you have discovered, a function may be uniformly continuous but the slope is unbounded.

Comment: I would describe it as **a** way of looking at it, not the 'best'.

Comment: @copper.hat This makes sense. One gripe I still have is how is the sqrtx and the rational function 1/x different in the sense of uniform continuity? they both have derivatives tending to an infinity, so what makes sqrtx uniformly continuous vs 1/x not uniformly continuous on [0,inf)?

Comment: This needs to be looked at on a case by case basis. The $\sqrt{\cdot}$ function is small when the derivative is small, so even a large slope does not change the value much, whereas the ${ 1 \over \cdot }$ function is large for small values of $x$.

Comment: I see, so this really stems back to the fact that the delta bounding the two arbitrary elements of the domain is dependant on the elements themselves. For the case of 1/x, delta must be scaled equivalent to the growth of the function to satisfy the definition where sqrtx doesn’t change as drastically. This helps a lot, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that you have found a *one way* relationship between derivatives and uniform continuity. *If* the derivative is bounded, *then* the function is uniformly continuous. The converse is certainly not true; the example you gave provides a nice counter example. It is NOT the case that if $f$ is uniformly continuous then $f'$ is bounded. This is all to say that there are some uniformly continuous functions that do not have bounded derivatives, while *all* functions with bounded derivatives are uniformly continuous.

In terms of your intuitive definition of uniform continuity: I would ask is there a point $x\in \text{dom} f$ for which the slope is the *largest* or *smallest* (possibly $\pm \infty$). For example, $$f:\left[0,\infty \right) \to \mathbf{R}$$
$$f(x)=\sqrt{x}$$ is uniformly continuous as its slope is "largest" at $x=0$ (very loosely speaking). Whereas, $$g:(0,\infty) \to \mathbf{R}$$ $$g(x)=\frac{1}{x}$$there is *no* $x\in (0,\infty)$ where the slope of $g$ is smallest; just scoot a little left to find a smaller slope.

Comment: I like this interpretation but I see potential minor flaw. For periodic functions like sine or cosine, we have no one point where the functions slope is smallest or largest but these functions are in fact still uniformly continuous. Maybe this interpretation is taken with a grain of salt but still something worth mentioning I guess

Comment: Ah, but I didn't say the point had to be unique. I do see the confusion with the word "largest" though. Perhaps, "maximized". For example, would you say I am wrong in saying that the slope of $\sin$ is the *largest* at $x=0$? I'd say so, it just happens to reach the same slope again at $x=2\pi, 4\pi,$ etc.

Comment: I see haha. Still very cool way of interpreting, I will couple this with a few other ways of thinking about it. thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

My favorite interpretation of uniform continuity is through the notion of "continuity at infinitely close points". The next theorem illustrates this idea:

> **Theorem.** Let $f : U \subseteq \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. Then the followings are equivalent:
>
> 1. $f$ is uniformly continuous (on $U$).
> 2. For any sequences $(a_n), (b_n)$ in $U$ such that $|a_n - b_n| \to 0$, we have $|f(a_n) - f(b_n)| \to 0$.

In Item 2, the sequence $(a_n)$ plays the role of "points in $U$ that are infinitely close to the boundary of $U$" and/or "infinitely large points in $U$". Hence, Item 2 tells that $f$ is uniformly continuous if and only if it is "continuous" even at such points.

Alternatively, but still heuristically, imagine there is a way of enlarging $\mathbb{R}$ by adding infinitesimals and infinitely large numbers, so that all the conventional quantities, objects, relations, etc. in $\mathbb{R}$ extends to the enlargement, say $\mathbb{R}^*$. (Let us also denote the extension of each object $x$ to the realm of $\mathbb{R}^*$ by $x^*$.) Then $f : U \subseteq \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is uniformly continuous if and only if $f^* : U^* \to \mathbb{R}^*$ is continuous, in the sense that if $x, y \in U^*$ are infinitesimally close, then $f^*(x)$ and $f^*(y)$ are infinitesimally close as well. (This is not a daydream, though. There is a mathematically rigorous way of materializing this idea, through the *hyperreal numbers* and ultraproduct.)

The next two examples demonstrate this heuristics:

> **Example 1.** Let $f : U = (0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ be given by $f(x) = 1/x$. We show that $f$ "fails to be continuous at a point in $U$ infinitely close to $\partial U$". Indeed, set $a_n = \frac{1}{n}$ and $b_n = \frac{1}{n+1}$. Then
>
> $$|a_n - b_n| \to 0 \qquad\text{but}\qquad |f(a_n) - f(b_n)| = 1 \not\to 0. $$
>
> Heuristically, let $N$ be infinitely large positive number, and let $x = \frac{1}{N}$ and $y = \frac{1}{N+1}$. Since $x > 0$, we have $x \in U^*$. Then $x$ and $y$ are infinitely close, but $f^*(x) - f^*(y) = -1$ is not.

> **Example 2.** Let $f : U = \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be given by $f(x) = x^2$. We then argue that $f$ "fails to be continuous at an infinitely large point in $U$". Indeed, set $a_n = n$ and $b_n = n + \frac{1}{n}$. Then
>
> $$|a_n - b_n| \to 0 \qquad\text{but}\qquad |f(a_n) - f(b_n)| = 2 + \frac{1}{n^2} \not\to 0. $$
>
> Likewise, letting $x = N$ and $y = N + \frac{1}{N}$ for infinitely large $N$ shows that $f^*$ is not continuous.

Comment: I've never seen such a definition of uniform continuity. Does this have a specific name or theorem which I can read more about? Also thank you for your answer this is an interesting way to approach this concept!